# Unfathomable Spring bug: service class not getting scanned

Tags: scala, spring-boot, model-view-controller

I've tried debugging this Spring related issue written in Scala for more than a week seriously, and I'm pretty desperate to seek for external helps. 
Basically, I have the app with some features on top of Spring working in one repo, but *due to the strict constraint for the code migration, I need to move this code to a new repo.*

Most of time, I separated in the new repo just the starting basics of a Spring app following this common module-based Gradle project structure

```
da-report
 |src
  |main
   |java
    com.abc.da.app
      service/
        ComService
      AppConfig 
      ComApp
  |resources
build.gradle
```

However, I've kept getting **the service class not get scanned/autowired in the main app class** for a very weird reason (it's so unfathomable that I couldn't understanding why it shouldn't work).

```
Field service in com.abc.da.app.service.ComApp required a bean of type 'com.abc.da.app.service.ComService' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.abc.da.app.service.ComService' in your configuration.
```

PS: apologize in advance if I show only the critical part of code (ignoring import statements and other configurations in YAML file)

I've *checked all necessary annotations or logics based on the working version * (in the previous repo) - in other words, these annotations  looks sufficient for autowiring (but weirdly they're not connected)

I've tried to either *change the service subpackage's location to the same level as the main app package directory*, but it's not working.

ComService

```
....
@Service
class ComService [
}
```

ComApp

```
...
object ComApp extends App {
 val cxt = new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(classOf[ComApp])).run(args: _*)
 println("contain service class? " + cxt.getBean("")) 
}

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(Array=(classOf[AppConfig]))
@EnableAutoConfiguration()
class ComApp extends ApplicationRunner {
  @Autowired var service: ComService = _
  override def run(applicationArguments: applicationArgument) ={
}
}
```

AppConfig

```
....
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = Array("com.abc.da.app.service"))
class AppConfig {
}
```

As said, the logics is completely disregarded to just test whether a service class gets recognized. I really expected any class under service subpackage gets scanned (even not needing to include @ComponentScan since the app class already is located in the root package)

So, I've banged my head but couldn't figure out what cause this weirdest bug. Could be because of the package naming? Is there any restriction on its naming logic & file structure that caused the bug?

Or could I make any silly, costly mistake(s) related to Spring semantics?

Answer (score 0):

I tried with Spring Boot 2.1.2.RELEASE on Scala 2.12.8 & JDK 1.8. Its working

```
//ComApp.scala
object ComApp extends App {
  val cxt = new SpringApplicationBuilder().sources(classOf[ComApp]).run(args: _*)
  println("contain service class? " + cxt.getBean("comService"))
}

@SpringBootApplication
@Import(value = Array(classOf[AppConfig]))
@EnableAutoConfiguration()
class ComApp extends ApplicationRunner {
  @Autowired var service: ComService = _
  override def run(applicationArguments: ApplicationArguments) ={

    service.demo("hello")
  }
}
//ComService.scala
@Service
class ComService {
  def demo(str: String): Unit = println(str) 
}

//AppConfig.scala
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = Array("com.abc.da.app.service"))
class AppConfig
```

I found some issue in your code

e.g. Import annotation should have value = Array not Array =

```
Import(value = Array(classOf[AppConfig]))

cxt.getBean(""))
```

This will give error as Bean name is empty

Hope this helps

Comment: hi @Himanshu, it's not working for my ends despite making that little tweak as aforementioned. I'm really frustrated by the anomaly of *@ComponentScan*, and the fact that the project structure looks good (still suspect something wrong related to this popular project structure in Spring Boo). Do u know any reasons why it doest work me.

Comment: Check your imports are you using correct packages. There are multiple @service annotations check if  using spring provided

Comment: Hi @Himanshu, I swear I tried all simple checks to this small module (significantly said I even put the service class in a same directory level as the app class to ignore the need of classpath scanning) but it doesn't work with the same errror as No qualifying bean of type com.abc.da.app.ComService. I am testified that every option including this option works in the old repo, but somehow this repo seems to break the classpath dependency everywhere. Is it the case here?